# Let a, b, c be three nonzero vectors, any two of which are perpendicular. Prove that these 3 vectors are linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is my answer:

We assume two cases, and work to prove that both assumptions are incorrect, leading to a proof.

1. Without loss of generality, assume that $ \mathbf{a} $ is linearly dependent with $ \mathbf{b} $

(similarly that $ \mathbf{a} $ is linearly dependent with $ \mathbf{c} $ and $ \mathbf{c} $ is linearly dependent with $ \mathbf{b} $ ).

1. Without loss of generality, assume that $ \mathbf{a} $ is linearly dependent with a linear combination of $ \mathbf{b} $ and $ \mathbf{c} $.

(And similarly, $ \mathbf{c} $ is linearly dependent with a linear combination of $ \mathbf{a} $ and $ \mathbf{b} $  or $ \mathbf{b} $ is linearly dependent with a linear combination of $ \mathbf{a} $ and $ \mathbf{c} $).

Case 1:

Assume $ \mathbf{a} = \alpha\mathbf{b}$  , so $ \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b}= \alpha\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{b}$

but  $\mathbf{a}$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf{b}$, so $ \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b}= 0 $,

but $ \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{b} = |\mathbf{b}|^2 \neq 0$

Therefore, case 1 is false.

Case 2:

Assume $ \mathbf{a} = \beta\mathbf{b} + \gamma\mathbf{c}$ so,

$ \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = (\beta\mathbf{b} + \gamma\mathbf{c}) \cdot \mathbf{b}$

$ = \beta\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{b} + \gamma\mathbf{c} \cdot \mathbf{b} = \beta(\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{b}) + \gamma(\mathbf{c} \cdot \mathbf{b}) $

$ \mathbf{b} $ is perpendicular to $ \mathbf{c} $ so,

$ \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = \beta(\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{b}) = \beta|\mathbf{b}|^2 \neq 0$

but $\mathbf{a}$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf{b}$, so again this is a contradiction.

Therefore, $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{c} $ are linearly Independent.

Is this a correct proof?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: But what if $\beta=0$?

Comment: It can't since it's the second case. If $\beta = 0$, then it'd be in the first case.

Comment: Let $a=c=(0,0,1), b=(0,1,0)$.  Case 1 doesn't apply, and in case 2, $\beta=0$.

Comment: @vadim123 But then $a$ and $c$ are not perpendicular.

Comment: Obviously $a,c$ will not be perpendicular since the result is true.  However the proof as written is incorrect because case 2 assumes $\beta\neq 0$.  To correct the original proof a case is needed where $\beta=0$ (and necessarily $\gamma\neq 0$).

Comment: I think that here we are given that $a,b,c$ are mutually perpendicular and from there we must prove that $a,b,c$ will necessarily be linearly independent. Then, the case of $\beta=0$ will be covered in the first case of the proof given by OP. Correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: Yes, milind is correct in that a,b,c are given to be mutually perpendicular. @vadim123 - I think you may have just overlooked this fact. Thanks to both of you for your input!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the proof is correct. There is a simpler proof that uses the same idea of taking the dot product of the linear dependence equation and the different vectors, however.

The vectors are independent iff $\alpha a+ \beta b+ \gamma c=0 \implies \alpha,\beta,\gamma=0$

So consider the equation again, $\alpha a+ \beta b+ \gamma c=0$. Now dot both sides with $a$ to get $\alpha=0$. Similarly $\beta=0$ and $\gamma=0$, and so $a,b,c$ are independent.

Comment: I was just about to type this!

Comment: It would be better to say "the vectors are independent if bla", rather than "if the vectors are independent, bla". Given that it is what you want to prove.

Comment: @julien Thank you, I edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Simpler proof (than OP): If $\mathbf{a, b,c}$ are dependent, we may write $\alpha \mathbf{a}+\beta\mathbf{b}+\gamma\mathbf{c}=0$ for some scalars $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, not all zero.  Without loss of generality $\alpha\neq 0$, so we may write $\mathbf{a}=(\beta/\alpha)\mathbf{b}+(\gamma/\alpha)\mathbf{c}$.  We have
$$0\neq \mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{a}\cdot((\beta/\alpha)\mathbf{b}+(\gamma/\alpha)\mathbf{c})=(\beta/\alpha)\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b}+(\gamma/\alpha)\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{c}=0$$